# Find inside comma separated values field Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I Need to check if a variable is present inside a comma separated string in mysql field using querybuilder.

I do this

```
 <?php 
      $parents = DB::table('categorie')>whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET("$categoria->id", parent)')->get();
```

but didn't return any value.

Comment: Your query is working?

Comment: Having a comma seperated string is in a database is **almost** always a bad idea. Consider redesigning your database architecture, so you won't run into these problems in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never put variables in the query yourself. Use bindings instead, this will make sure your parameters are correctly escaped.

```
<?php 
    $parents = DB::table('categorie')->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?, parent)', [$categoria->id])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may debug the query using toSql() method after your query, which becomes

```
DB::table('categorie')->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET("$categoria->id", parent)')->toSql();
```

This will clear it out if $categoria->id is being put in the query or not.

> I can't comment yet, hence posting it as an answer.

Comment: I think the query is $parents = DB::table('categorie')->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET('".$categoria->id."', parent)")->get();

Comment: That is not the query that SQL will be executing. Using toSql() method gives the query, exactly as it would be executed in SQL. The query given is just an instance of Query Builder which translates to the sql query before executing.